Custom vibration like happy/bad feedback
In my .NET 8 MAUI application, I have a list of questions and want to give the user feedback when the answers are right or wrong. I can use a small sound for it, but I also prefer vibration. So, I prepared a VibrationService for it
public class VibrationService
{
    public void VibrateForCorrectAnswer()
    {
        // Short vibration for correct answer
        #if ANDROID || IOS
            Vibration.Default.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
        #endif
    }

    public void VibrateForWrongAnswer()
    {
        // Longer vibration for wrong answer
        #if ANDROID || IOS
            Vibration.Default.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        #endif
    }
}

I was looking around to see if it is possible to change this vibration to give the user nice feedback. For example, if the answer is correct, the vibration should be something that makes the user happy. I know it is funny to read, but I don't know if it is possible to "compose" simple "songs" and how.

Given the question is primarily about creating patterns of vibration, does it make sense to include C# and MAUI tags?

The source code is in C# and MAUI. So, I think so.

you would need to implement this using platform APIs for each platform.  MAUI does not have a standard interface for creating custom haptics

Below I implemented the effect for different vibration frequencies on different platforms. This is done through the partial class. Of course, conditional compilation can also be used.For more information about
Conditional compilation Please refer to the
Invoke platform code.
Here's how to implement a button click on the Mainpage page to achieve the vibration frequency effect on different platforms.
The partial class is named VirationService, which includes a partial method named Vibrate. The code file for this class must be outside of the Platforms folder:
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
       private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          VibrationService vibrationService = new VibrationService();
           long[] pattern = { 0, 10, 1000, 300 };
           vibrationService.Vibrate(pattern, -1);         
       }
 
   }

   public partial class VibrationService
   {
       public partial void Vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat);
   }

The following is the code under Platform/Android, using the Android native platform vibration API, for related information, please refer to VibrationEffect.CreateWaveform Method.
'pattern' is an array, the odd number of columns controls the start time, and the even number of columns controls the time of vibration.
  public partial class VibrationService
  {
      public partial void Vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
      {
          var vibrator = (Vibrator)MainActivity.Instance.GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
          if (vibrator != null)
          {
              if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
              {
                  VibrationEffect effect = VibrationEffect.CreateWaveform(pattern, repeat);
                  vibrator.Vibrate(effect);
              }
              else
              {
                  vibrator.Vibrate(pattern, repeat);

              }
          }
      }
  }


The following is the content of the VibrationService located in Platform/iOS, which uses the PlaySystemSound api in ios to implement a vibration effect to achieve a certain intermittent delay vibration.
  public partial class VibrationService
   {
       public partial void Vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
       {
           foreach (var duration in pattern) {
 
               SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound();
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)duration);
           }
       }
   }

